# com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate google play services

Tags: android, adview

Although this question is asked bundle of times but none of the solution worked for me. I m using Google play Service Library to put on ads in my application. 
i have declared it in menifest file as well and everything is correct according to Google documentation but still i get this error. 
i declared the adView like this in layout file:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
 android:layout_width="480dp"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:gravity="bottom"
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
 ads:adUnitId="a1514181aaf0886"
 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
 ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"/>
```

The Logcat is as follows

```
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to               start activity ComponentInfo{com.pucit.newgame/com.pucit.newgame.newgame}:      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:360)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1932)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at com.pucit.newgame.newgame.onCreate(newgame.java:93)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     ... 11 more
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     ... 23 more
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ao.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-26 13:35:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(9190):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
```